# retrieve image from sql in c#

Tags: c#, sql, image

I am able to successfully store image in SQL DB, 
There is a field for image as varchar50. 
This is the code that I tried

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
dt=neworder.Selectfromimage1();

if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{

 // byte[] image =(byte[])dt.Rows[0]["image"];
 byte image=Convert.ToByte(dt.Rows[0]["image"]);
 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(image);
 //stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
 stream.Seek(0,

 SeekOrigin.Begin);
 stream.Close();

 btncompanion.Image =

 Image.FromStream(stream);
 }
```

I am getting error "Input string was not in corret format " 
on

```
byte image=Convert.ToByte(dt.Rows[0]["image"]);
```

**EDITED**

Code for saving image is

```
private byte[] ImageToStream(string fileName)
{

 MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
 tryagain:

 try
 {

  Bitmap image = new Bitmap(fileName);
  image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

  // image.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
 }

 catch (Exception )
 {

  goto tryagain;
 }

 return stream.ToArray();
}
fName ="C:\\Documents and Settings\\KAEM\\My Documents\\My Pictures\\images.jpg";
if (File.Exists(fName))
{

 int id = 2;
 byte[] content = ImageToStream(fName);
 if (neworder.Insertintoimage1(content.ToString()))
 {

}

}

else
{

 MessageBox.Show(fName + " not found ");
}
```

Comment: do you store the image bytes of just the file system path to the image?

Comment: yes, just the path, I added the code for saving as well please check

Comment: `goto`?? Are you nuts??

Answer (score 1):

You store the path to the image in your database.
Your code should look like this:

```
string imagePath=dt.Rows[0]["image"].ToString();
            byte[] imageBytes;
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(imagePath)) {
                 btncompanion.Image = Image.FromStream(fs);
            }
```

Try this, not tested

Comment: He does not store the path if you look closely. But he stores the image bytes as string, which is bad.

Answer (score 1):

You are closing the stream before you're trying to read. That doesn't work. You should try the following:

```
byte[] image=Convert.ToByte(dt.Rows[0]["image"]);
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(image))
{
    btncompanion.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
}
```

If that doesn't work and gives a GDI+ error, then that is because the stream is closed before the image is deserialized. In that case use this:

```
byte image=Convert.ToByte(dt.Rows[0]["image"]);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(image);
btncompanion.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Also, in the code that stores the image, you get the bytes from the image file, but pass them as `string` to the database. You are aware of the fact that image bytes can contains non-printable bytes that are removed from a string or terminate the string?

Do not store the image as string or at least use base 64 encoding for that. The code for that would read:

```
if (File.Exists(fName))
{
    byte[] content = ImageToStream(fName);
    string contentBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(content);
    if (neworder.Insertintoimage1(contentBase64))
        ....
}
```

And to retrieve:

```
string image = dt.Rows[0]["image"];
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(image);

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
btncompanion.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Comment: The last line of which code sample? My suggestion is to not use a string to store the image at all, but to use a `BINARY` field, which is a `byte[]` in C#. That way you don't have to convert anything.

Comment: yours @Thorsten Dittmar of retrieving 

string image = dt.Rows[0]["image"];
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(image);

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);
btncompanion.Image = Image.FromStream(stream);

Comment: Of course you're talking about my code samples - I wanted to know which line exactly. Did you store a base 64 coded string in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to figure out how the data was encoded to produce the varchar string. For example, if it were base64, you would use [`Convert.FromBase64String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string.aspx):

```
byte[] image = Convert.FromBase64String(dt.Rows[0]["image"])
```

Now, since you're the one storing the image, you should know how it is encoded and should be able to do the reverse process to get it back.

Comment: I added the code to save as well, please see, if there is anything missing